# Reducing execution time of join to SQLXML table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

I have a large T-SQL stored procedure which contains 3 joins to `SELECT` statements which query XML values passed in as parameters.

The parameters look like this:

```
@Code xml = NULL
```

The joins look like this:

```
    AND (@Code IS NULL OR (t.Code IN (
        select Tbl.Col.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(2)')
        from @Code.nodes('//codes/code') Tbl(Col)
    )))
```

An example of a parameter value is:

```
'<codes><code>GB</code></codes>'
```

The could be as many as 100 `<code>...</code>` elements within these blocks.

Every element displayed on the execution plan shows `Cost: 0 %` except for these joins, which show `Cost: 49 %`.

Is there anything I can do to improve execution time?

Comment: I'd suggest you use Table Valued Parameters, which would probably perform better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `//` descendant axis is slow, try to use the normal `/` child axis.

Also, using `.` to retrieve the node value is also slow, better to use `text()`

You could do one of the following syntaxes, which are likely to be faster than what you have

```
    AND (@Code IS NULL OR
        @Code.exist('/codes/code[text() = sql:column("t.Code")]')) = 1
    )

-- or better

    AND ISNULL(@Code.exist('/codes/code[text() = sql:column("t.Code")]'), 1) = 1
```

```
    AND (@Code IS NULL OR (t.Code IN (
        select Tbl.Col.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(2)')
        from @Code.nodes('/codes/code') Tbl(Col)
    )))
```